# How can I properly encode a GLTF while also preserving the encoding of other meshes and textures?

Tags: javascript, encoding, three.js, lighting, gltf

I'm building a web ar app that allows users to wear GLTF head models. (https://www.head5.camera/) In order to get the correct lighting on the GLTF, I have set `renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding` and this works great BUT it also adjusts the lighting of my `THREE.VideoTexture` from my video stream. Is there a way to encode just the GLTF but preserve the *LinearEncoding?* of the rest of the scene. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: Head5 photo with light background]

The background is lighter than it is supposed to be because it is also being encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output encoding is a renderer-level setting and cannot be changed for specific objects or materials. Because you can only have one `renderer.outputEncoding`, it's necessary that you stick consistently to either a gamma workflow or a linear workflow ([background reading](https://www.donmccurdy.com/2020/06/17/color-management-in-threejs/)).

THREE.GLTFLoader configures materials and textures with the assumption that you're using a linear workflow, and that requires `renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding` (or equivalent post-processing). It sounds like the rest of your scene is configured for a gamma workflow. To make those consistent you'll probably want to traverse the whole scene (including both glTFs and any other models / textures) and configure the colorspace of the relevant textures.

```
scene.traverse((object) => {
  if (object.isMesh) {
    const material = object.material;
    if (material.map) material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    if (material.emissiveMap) material.emissiveMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    if (material.sheenColorMap) material.sheenColorMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    if (material.specularColorMap) material.specularColorMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  }
});
```

With those changes, sRGB output encoding for a "linear workflow" will look correct. You can also do the opposite – switching these textures to `THREE.LinearEncoding` — if you want to use linear output encoding for a "gamma workflow". That might be easier if you have a lot of other content in the scene.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to thoroughly answer it. Here's the outcome: https://www.head5.camera/